# Synonyms of (不会)少块肉?

Tags: synonyms

I'm quite fond of the phrase 少块肉, as in `又不会少块肉` or `能少块肉吗？`.

- What synonyms of 少块肉 exist in Chinese?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sometimes we use "死不了" in similar situations. For example:

1 别抽烟了，忍一忍，死不了。
2 不用担心，死不了。

Hope this can be of some help.

Answer (score 2):

把烟熄了，少抽一支又不能少块肉。

=

把烟熄了，少抽一支又不能死。

=

把烟熄了，少抽一支又不能怎样。

=

把烟熄了，少抽一支没什么损失。

Answer (score 1):

不妨 or 无妨 come to mind, surely there are others.

Comment: 无妨 is one of the synonyms, in a sense of "it wouldn't hurt to XXXXX", so I upvoted the answer.